# Convert one type into another type in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I tried to add values into dictionary. But I faced casting problem.
Here My Sample code.

```
public class Column
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Table: Dictionary<string, Column>
{
}

SortedDictionary<string, Table> tableSc = new SortedDictionary<string, Table>();
foreach (var table in item.Tables)
                {
                    Dictionary<string, Column> col = new Dictionary<string, Column>();
                    foreach (var column in table.Fields)
                    {
                        Column value = new Column();
                        value.Name = column.Id;
                        col.Add(column.Id, value);
                    }
                    tableSc.Add(table.Id, (Table)col);
                }
```

I got below exception when adding Table type value into `tableSc` dictionary.

`(tableSc.Add(table.Id, (Table)col);)`

> **Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,Column]' to
>   type 'Table'.**

Can anyone suggest me how I resolve this?

Comment: Use: tableSc.Add(table.Id, table); How you think column can be cast as table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way you declare variable `col`

```
Table col = new Table(); // or another construtor
```

Your class `Table` inherited from `Dictionary`, so you can not cast object of `Dictionary` to its child classes.